# How to pass a variable(type string) as an index in a dictionary

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am working on a an encryptor and want to change every single letter of a string into a number.

In my `for` loop, I need `inputArray[i]` to equal `pairs.inputArray[i]`.

This does not work because it fills in (for example) `pairs.'w'` but it has to be `pairs.w` in order to work.

```js
var pairs = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 4,
  'e': 5,
  'f': 6,
  'g': 7,
  'h': 8,
  'i': 9,
  'j': 10,
  'k': 11,
  'l': 12,
  'm': 13,
  'n': 14,
  'o': 15,
  'p': 16,
  'q': 17,
  'r': 18,
  's': 19,
  't': 20,
  'u': 21,
  'v': 22,
  'w': 23,
  'x': 24,
  'y': 25,
  'z': 26,
  ' ': 27
}

// var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26];
// var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
// var alphabetArray = alphabet.split('');

var input = 'raising';
var inputArray = input.split('');

for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
  //var index = inputArray[i];
  inputArray[i] = pairs.inputArray[i];
}

console.log(inputArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bracket notation instead of dot notation like this

`pairs[inputArray[i]]`

```js
var pairs = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 4,
  'e': 5,
  'f': 6,
  'g': 7,
  'h': 8,
  'i': 9,
  'j': 10,
  'k': 11,
  'l': 12,
  'm': 13,
  'n': 14,
  'o': 15,
  'p': 16,
  'q': 17,
  'r': 18,
  's': 19,
  't': 20,
  'u': 21,
  'v': 22,
  'w': 23,
  'x': 24,
  'y': 25,
  'z': 26,
  ' ': 27
}
var inputArray = Array.from('raising');

for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
  inputArray[i] = pairs[inputArray[i]];
}

console.log(inputArray.join(","));
```

Comment: how the hell did I edit an answer while writing my own, screen not big enough? Sorry :)

Comment: @Fran No problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bracket notation instead of dot notation to access the value, similar to `inputArray[i] = pairs[inputArray[i]];`

See documentation on [**Property Accessors**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) for more details.

```js
var pairs = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 4,
  'e': 5,
  'f': 6,
  'g': 7,
  'h': 8,
  'i': 9,
  'j': 10,
  'k': 11,
  'l': 12,
  'm': 13,
  'n': 14,
  'o': 15,
  'p': 16,
  'q': 17,
  'r': 18,
  's': 19,
  't': 20,
  'u': 21,
  'v': 22,
  'w': 23,
  'x': 24,
  'y': 25,
  'z': 26,
  ' ': 27
}

// var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26];
// var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
// var alphabetArray = alphabet.split('');

var input = 'raising';
var inputArray = input.split('');

for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
  //var index = inputArray[i];
  inputArray[i] = pairs[inputArray[i]];
}

console.log(inputArray);
```